# How to define a custom ckeditor toolbar in the page markup

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ckeditor

I'm able to define a custom toolbar for a ckeditor control in asp.net using just the ToolbarBasic property within the page markup. I do it like this:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="100%" Toolbar="Basic"
ToolbarBasic="|Bold|Italic|Underline|Strike|-|NumberedList|BulletedList|Outdent|Indent|-|JustifyLeft|JustifyCenter|JustifyRight|JustifyBlock|-|Link|Unlink|-|TextColor|-|Undo|Redo|Cut|Copy|Paste|PasteText|PasteFromWord|-|Find|Replace|SelectAll|-|Image|Table|HorizontalRule|SpecialChar|-|Format|" ></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

This creates a custom toolbar with all of the specified items within the same "section" i.e. they are sort of grouped together. Where a |-| is specified, this creates a small vertical line between the items but the items remain in the same "section". I can see that when using the standard "Full" toolbar, the items are split into multiple sections but I'm not sure how to do that using the above syntax.

Unfortunately I don't remember where I originally found this syntax online and have taken it from an old project of mine. Now I cant find any information about this syntax online and all searches give information about defining a custom toolbar in different ways.

The version of ckeditor I'm using is 3.6.6.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably found the original syntax here: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Configuration

To answer your question, a new line creates a new section and a / puts the buttons on the next row.

Using your example:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="100%" Toolbar="Basic"
ToolbarBasic="|Bold|Italic|Underline|Strike|-|NumberedList|BulletedList|Outdent|Indent|-|JustifyLeft|JustifyCenter|JustifyRight|JustifyBlock|
|Link|Unlink|-|TextColor|-|Undo|Redo|Cut|Copy|Paste|PasteText|PasteFromWord|
/
|Find|Replace|SelectAll|-|Image|Table|HorizontalRule|SpecialChar|-|Format|" ></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

This will add a section gap between `JustifyBlock` and `Link`, as well as shift the buttons on to the second row after `PasteFromWord`.

You can also do away with setting that text in `ToolbarBasic` and just set it straight in the `Toolbar` attribute if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to make the edits here where it says to: \Scripts\ckeditor\config.js

```html
/*
Copyright (c) 2003-2012, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
 // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
 // config.language = 'fr';
 // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.removePlugins = 'save';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor toolbar can be adjusted to your needs. You can define a toolbar that contains all the buttons available in the Full toolbar definition using the following code:

```
                                    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEdMainPageDescriptionWebsiteMobileappEn" BasePath="ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="100%" Toolbar="Basic"
                                        ToolbarBasic="|Bold|Italic|Underline|Strike|-|NumberedList|BulletedList|Outdent|Indent|-|JustifyLeft|JustifyCenter|JustifyRight|JustifyBlock|
                                        |Link|Unlink|-|TextColor|-|Undo|Redo|Cut|Copy|Paste|PasteText|PasteFromWord|
                                          /
                                        |Styles|-|Format|-|Font|-|FontSize|"> </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

http://thecallingtree.com/ToolbarDefine.aspx